# Iterate through all sinks and enrichers registered in Serilog

Tags: serilog, sink

How can I iterate through all **sinks** (`ILogEventSink` objects) or enrichers (`ILogEventEnricher` objects), respective, registered in Serilog?
I'm using `Serilog.AspNetCore`.

Thanks.

So, my naive idea is:
In Emit operation I must call a third party service that require current HttpContext to be set. 
It seems Emit operation runs on background thread that has not got HttpContext assigned. So in Emit operation, I want to resolve IHttpContextAccesor service and set its HttpContext property. Then I can call a third party service requiring HttpContext to be set and all will be fine.
The current httpContext instance I will get is in my custom middleware and just here is the place where I want to inject httpContext instance into **the Sink instance** (to its  [ThreadStatic] field) to accomplish scenario described above.

Another way is recreating all Serilog (and its Sink) in a middleware on each http request and pass httpContext to its constructor as a parameter. Expensive.

Comment: If you're able to post a follow-up question describing your scenario, there might be another way to look at it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Serilog doesn't support this scenario.